# Segmentation fault error in BST

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault error when I call the find_word function in my main.
when a word is added I want to return 1 and when it finds that word, I want it to return 1.
So I'm also not sure if my insert method is correct either.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    char *word;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
static struct node *root;


int init(void)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    if(new_node==NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    else{
        root = new_node;
        new_node->left = NULL;
        new_node->right = NULL;
        return 1;
    }
}

static int insert(struct node *newnode, char *word)
{
    struct node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(newnode))
        {
            temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->left =NULL;
            temp->right = NULL;
            temp->word = word;
            newnode = temp;
            return 0;
        }

    if(word < (newnode)->word)
        {
            insert((newnode)->left, word);
        }
    else if(word > (newnode)->word)
        {
            insert((newnode)->right, word);
        }
    return 1;
}

int add_word(char *word)
{
    return insert(root,word);

}
static int find(char *word, struct node *newnode){
    if(newnode==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(strcmp(word,newnode->word)>0){
        find(word,newnode->left);
    }

    else if(strcmp(newnode->word,word)<0){
        find(word,newnode->right);
    }
    else{

        return 1;

    }
    return 0;
}


int find_word(char *word)
{
    return find(word,root);
}




int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int k;
    char l[5];


    k = init();
    printf("init: %d\n",k);

    strcpy(l,"x");
    k = add_word(l);
    printf("add_word(%s): %d\n",l,k);

    strcpy(l,"x");
    k = find_word(l);
    printf("find_word(%s): %d\n",l,k);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `insert` should use `strcmp` to compare `word` with `newnode->word`, not `<` and `>`.

Comment: @Barmar I changed it, so its now `strcmp(word,newnode->word)>0` and `strcmp(word,newnode->word)<0`  in `insert` but I still get a segmentation error.

Comment: Didn't you post a similar question earlier? It looks like it's been deleted, because I can't find it now. As I suggested there, run your code under the debugger so you can see which variables are invalid when the error happens.

Comment: I did, but i thought this would give more context. I'll try debugging.

Comment: You could have just updated the original question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: I don't know how to debug much, but I all i know is that the the change you suggested is causing the error and i keep getting error messages on the debugger.

Comment: `insert` isn't checking whether `newnode->word` is NULL before comparing it to `word`.

Comment: This will cause errors when you try to add to the root, because its word is NULL.

Comment: @Barmar So would I have to write `if newnode->word != NULL` in `insert`?

Comment: I posted an answer that shows what you have to do.

Comment: It is executing, but in my `find` function doesn't work. It won't return `0` if there is no `b` in the tree if you look inside the main for my test cases.

Comment: In your code, you're not making a copy of the string when you put it into the tree, you're just storing a pointer to the original string. And you're using the same `l` array when you insert and find. So it will always find it, because you're modifying what's in the tree.

Comment: So what do I need to do if I want to find the string in the tree, and return 0 when its not there?

Comment: You should change your `insert` function so it makes a copy of `word` and store that.

Comment: I thought that's what my `insert` function was doing. What am I missing? What i mean is, how do I convert the pointer to a string copy?

Comment: What part of your `insert` function makes a copy of the string? It just does `newnode->word = word`. That assigns the pointer, it doesn't make a copy of the string.

Comment: ah ok. I think i got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix like this

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    char *word;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

static struct node *root = NULL;

static int insert(struct node **newnode, char *word){
    struct node *temp = NULL;
    int cmp;

    if(!*newnode){
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->left =NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->word = strdup(word);
        *newnode = temp;
        return 0;
    }

    if((cmp=strcmp(word, (*newnode)->word)) < 0)
        return insert(&(*newnode)->left, word);
    if(cmp > 0)
        return insert(&(*newnode)->right, word);
    return 1;
}

int add_word(char *word){
    return insert(&root, word);
}

static int find(char *word, struct node *newnode){
    int cmp;
    if(newnode==NULL)
        return 0;
    if((cmp=strcmp(word, newnode->word)) == 0)
        return 1;
    if(cmp < 0)
        return find(word, newnode->left);
    return find(word, newnode->right);
}

int find_word(char *word){
    return find(word, root);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int k;
    char *w;

    k = add_word(w="x");
    printf("add_word(%s): %d\n", w, k);

    k = find_word(w);
    printf("find_word(%s): %d\n", w, k);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `newnode->word` is NULL, you should insert the word at the current node, to handle the empty root node.

```
static int insert(struct node *newnode, char *word)
{
    struct node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(newnode))
        {
            temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->left =NULL;
            temp->right = NULL;
            temp->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
            strcpy(temp->word, word);
            newnode = temp;
            return 0;
        }

    if (newnode->word == NULL) {
        newnode->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
        strcpy(newnode->word, word);
        return 1;
    }

    if(strcmp(word,(newnode)->word) < 0)
        {
            insert((newnode)->left, word);
        }
    else if(strcmp(word,(newnode)->word) > 0)
        {
            insert((newnode)->right, word);
        }
    return 1;
}
```

In your `find` function, you call `strcmp` twice. You swap the order of the arguments, but you also change `> 0` to `< 0`. These cancel each other out, so both are testing the same thing. You need to change one or the other, but not both. You should also check for `newnode->word == NULL`.

```
static int find(char *word, struct node *newnode){
    if(newnode==NULL || newnode->word == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(strcmp(word,newnode->word)>0){
        find(word,newnode->left);
    }

    else if(strcmp(word,newnode->word)<0){
        find(word,newnode->right);
    }
    else{

        return 1;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to make a copy of `word` when inserting it into the tree.

Comment: It still outputs that `b` is still found even though its not added. I'm confused.

Comment: Fixed your `find` function.

Comment: Ok so it returns `0` with no `b` but still returns `0` when `abc` is added? Even though I understand now that I was checking the same thing twice.

Comment: Sorry, I'm done debugging your program for you. How do you ever expect to become a programmer if you can't figure out how to do this by yourself? Use a debugger, set breakpoints, single-step through the program to see what it's doing.

Comment: I was never taught how to do it. I'm sorry. It's very confusing stuff.

Comment: Sorry, but I have better things to do (it's my dinner time), I'm not going to spend another hour figuring out why your program doesn't work. I already fixed 3 or 4 of your bugs. You need to learn to solve your own programs. Google for tutorials on using gdb.

Comment: It's your call if you want to walk away. I can respect that. I'm just someone who is trying to learn by example.